# Angular 2: HTTP Post Request with URL parameters and body type parameter

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to make an HTTP POST request with Angular 2 as below.

```
saveUserSelection() {
    var json = JSON.stringify({access_token: localStorage.getItem('access_token')});
    var params = 'json=' + json;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    return this.http
        .post('http://localhost:8080/user/selection', params, { headers: headers })
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

But I am getting an error as below.

> angular2.dev.js:23877 EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "ngSubmit"
>       ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': '[object Object]' is not a valid HTTP header field name.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with my code? And how can I create a HTTP POST request with parsing body type parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
headers.append('access_token', localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
```

Comment: I need to pass access_token as a parameter. It's a string. Also I need to pass String Array as a body type parameter. How to do it?

Comment: Above error is gone but now it tells **HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'access_token' is not present**

Comment: Then how to pass a body type parameter?

Comment: I need to pass a String Array in the request body

Comment: Currently only string is supported as body type AFAIK. If you need something else you need to make the request using something different than Angulars `Http`.

Comment: In Angular 1 we are using body attribute to pass parameters (ex: **params : {
                access_token : localStorage.getItem("access_token")
            },
            data : $scope.selection_array**). How do we do it in Angular 2?